# IBM Mobilefirst CLI 7.1.0 mfp push ERROR

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, command-line-interface, mobilefirst-cli

I type in "mfp start" into the terminal and get:

**The server is running.**

I then type in "mfp push" into the terminal and get:

**Preparing for push...
Error: error code :126
Error: The MobileFirst server that you have configured does not appear to be running. Start the server with 'mobilefirst start'.
Error: SERVERNOTRUNNING
Error: Push has failed**

I am confused as to why I am getting these errors when I have started the server and when I started the server I did not get any errors. How do I successfully run mfp push without getting errors?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check whether your server is actually running by opening Mobile First Operations Console in browser ??

Comment: And are you within the project when you execute mfp push?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of project you are trying mfp push for? Behavior of mfp push varies based on the type pf project you are in. Please refer https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/advanced-client-side-development/using-cli-to-create-build-and-manage-mobilefirst-project-artifacts/ for more details.